# PHP + Modular structure + Includes

Tags: php, data-structures, directory, modular

I'm trying to make a backend panel in my websites, so that every customer can manage basic settings. My idea is make it modular, so i have the following folder structure:

- css
- img
- lib
- modules
- - users
- - - default.php
- - - single-user.php
- - - user-list.php
- - - functions.php
- - categories
- - - default.php
- - - functions.php
- php
- index.php
- .htaccess

What's the best way to handle this structure. I thinking using the index.php to includes modules files, for example:

mysite.com/admin/users/single-user?id=1
transform in
mysite.com/admin/index.php?module=users&view=single-user

I appreciate any ideas, thanks so much!

Comment: You might check out this answer over at Programmers. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/120958/55187

Comment: you'll will certainly HAVE to use url rewrite. to url rewrite, you basically modify some rules in your .htaccess file in your root folder. Have a look at this article `http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/02/introduction-to-url-rewriting/`